# Wagtail ModelAdmin: Does not hide widget label

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I have written an own panel that utilizes the django modeladmin. The modeladmin is connected to another model via a foreign key, but I dont want the user to be able to change the foreign key relation, only the other data on the form. I have therefor tried to hide the widget via the panels argument on the model admin:

```
    panels = [
    FieldPanel("event_detail", widget=HiddenInput),
    FieldPanel("title"),
    FieldPanel("content"),
    FieldPanel("send_time"),
]
```

This handles the input field correctly in the modeladmin, but sadly I still see the label in the modeladmin, which will confuse my users. How can I make sure that not only the field is removed but also the label?

[image]

Comment: Why not just leave `event_detail` out of the `panels` list?

Comment: @gasman I need to have that key in order to be able to save it to the database, its a required field in the db...

Comment: If it's a required field, then making it a hidden field isn't going to help either, because there's no way for the user to fill it in. Or do you have some custom Javascript automatically populating it?

Comment: @gasman Leaving it out works when editing existing instances, what Im struggling with is the CreateView... how do I get the id of the foreign relation into the model before saving it to the db?

Comment: @gasman right now Im trying by leaving it out like you said and populating it via a session variable before saving the model, but not sure if that is the right pattern?

Comment: It depends where the value for this field is meant to be coming from - you haven't explained that. All I know is that it's not part of this form. However, at this point I think you should ask this as a fresh question, as it's nothing to do with the form rendering.

Comment: @gasman, your right. I created a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57325447/wagtail-modeladmin-pass-data-to-create-view-class